# Symfony 4 - Rest API Cross Domain JSON_Login

Tags: php, json, api, symfony, authentication

I'm a totally new Symfony 4 user and I want to create a rest API with a normal username: password login.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/json_login_setup.html
I thought this is the way to handle the task but after I send a request with username and password, I can't get my content.

Here is my code:
(security.yaml)

```
security:
    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\ApUser
                property: username

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            json_login:
                check_path: login
            provider: our_db_provider
            logout:
                path:   logout

    encoders:
        App\Entity\ApUser:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_USER
```

(UserController.php)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

use App\Entity\ApCustomerUser;
use App\Entity\ApUser;
use App\Azuplay\Validator\ValidateString;
use App\Azuplay\Validator\ValidateNumber;


class UserController extends FOSRestController
{
   /**
     * @Rest\Post("/login", name="login")
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
    }
}
```

If I send a post request with correct username and password, the server returns 200 OK and with incorrect it returns 401. So I guess the user check works.
But after correct login, the server returns 500 "Full authentication is required to access this resource." if I request a /user for example.

Here are more informations:

Example-User:

```
id: 2
username: ****
email: ****
Password: ***
roles: ROLE_USER
```

Ajax-Request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain : true,
            url : http://myAPIDomain.de/login OR http://myAPIDomain.de/user,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
})
.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            })
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
});
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with axios and cross domain requests. For me, setting the request parameter "withCredentials: true" helped. So in your case it should be:

```js
jQuery.ajax({
            crossDomain : true,
            url : http://myAPIDomain.de/login OR http://myAPIDomain.de/user,
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
})
...
```